How to tell GNU linker to only try to find unresolved symbol so far from a specific static library?
I added some symbols into a existing src file, this src file is used by both the main program and an independent library. The added symbols belong to the main program hence locate in a static library where symbols come from a variety of sources.
To make the independent library able to include the definitions of added symbols, I make ld link the static library where the added symbols locate, however, like explained above, the static library itself includes so many external symbols, it's hence impossible to include all dependencies here.
I was thus wondering, is there any way to let linker only try to find unresolved symbols, i.e., the newly added symbols in this case, from specific libraries? say, what I have before this change is
EXTRA_LIBS := $(addprefix $(LOC_TOOLS)/foo/bar/, lib1.a lib2.a 

Now I would like linker to find ONLY unresolved symbols from lib3.a, i.e., care not all symbols in lib3.a but the one needed by lib2.a.
Is there any ld options and so on that allow me to achieve  this? or should I simply define the undefined yet unused symbols in a separate dummy src file then link it?

EDIT1
After some browsing and reading, I am convinced that there is no such "partial fetch" function given by ld.
However, I am still interested in why GNU does not offer such a function like what they give to shared library? Does it have something to do with PIC?
On the other hand, as some fellows point out, the linker does a sing-pass consultation on object linked and fetch ALL symbols in the object. But strangely, I observed weird things more than once in my development:

Say I have lib1 and lib2 that covers all the symbols (they should do right? as they are linked ok, if any missed the link shall fail), now a symbol defined in lib1 is added to lib2's src file and recompiled, in this case, no change is needed right? as lib1's symbols are already fetched by linker, but I get error saying undefined reference of the newly added symbol.

For the same example as #1, now I appended lib1 again next lib2, EXTRA_LIBS := $(addprefix $(LOC_TOOLS)/foo/bar/, lib1.a lib2.a lib1.a, it gives error saying many undefined reference in lib1.a, but should they have already been resolved given that all symbols are fetched for each linked library that actually is depended?



EDIT2
Hi fellows, I really appreciate the answers and comments, they do a great help. Now I only have one single piece of detail to ensure:
Does link fetch all symbol definitions of a library to be linked, or just the symbol definitions needed so far?
Could anyone be so kind to share me the doc, hopefully from GNU official, where related behavior is defined?

The linker links the objects from the library archive that fulfill the unresolved symbols.  Doesn't that already fulfill your request?  Or isn't it working that way for you for some reason?

@Eljay lib3.a itself has undefined symbols and needs to be resolved by further including other libraries, by nm command I can find those symbols marked "U"

There is no lib3.a in your command line. So it's not easy to follow you. --- Well, each time you add a libXXX.a to the EXTRA_LIBS, the linker will search all object files in libXXX.a if it can resolve an undefined symbol. If it finds a match, that entire object file from the lib is linked. Other object files are not used. The just linked object file can have further unresolved externals. These will cause the linker to scan the current lib once again. If you want to get one specific object file, you should make sure not further unresolved externals are found.

When you say "a synbol is added to lib2", I assume what you really mean is that a reference to a symbol is added; that is, now lib2 has an unresolved reference to a symbol in lib1.  The behavior in #1 is to be expected (for single-pass linkers, such as GNU ld).  For #2, there must be something else happening here.  For example, if the first pass of lib1 didn't need some symbols from lib2, but then the second pass of lib1 did need those symbols, you'll get link errors.  All you have to do is look at the symbols and where they're defined.

@Madscientist, but doesn't this mean only needed symbols but not all symbols are fetched by linker? This is the very point that I want to be certain about, any related official materials are greatly appreciated.

Suppose object file O.o in a static library defines symbols AAA and BBB, and it references undefined symbols XXX, YYY, and ZZZ.  If, when the linker reaches this static library, either of the symbols AAA or BBB are in the linker's list of undefined symbols then the entire contents of O.o will be linked, the symbols AAA and BBB will be added to the list of defined symbols, and XXX, YYY, and ZZZ will be added to the list of undefined symbols that still need to be linked.

This is how the linker works for static libraries, broadly:
First, all your object files are collected and their symbols stored.  The linker now has a set of symbols defined by your object files, and a set of undefined symbols referenced by your object files.
For each static library, each object file in the static library is checked and if that object contains one or more defined symbol that is in the current set of undefined symbols, then that object file is included in the link and all the symbols it defines are added to the set of defined symbols (and removed from the set of undefined symbols, if they are present).  All the undefined symbols in that object file are added to the set of undefined symbols.  This library will be consulted until everything that might be available and needed by this library, is added.
Then the linker moves to the next library, and repeats.  Note that these are "single-pass" linkers which means once they've decided they have everything that is needed and available they'll never come back to that library, so ordering the libraries on the link line is important.
At the end of the command line, if there are any symbols left in the set of undefined symbols those are shown as errors and the link fails.
The important thing to note, as hinted at by the comments above, is that the linker can only link whole object files.  It can't extract a single symbol (like a single function) from an object file and link only that: it must take the entire content of the object file (a static library is basically just a collection of object files with an index on it).
It's not clear from your question but if the problem is that you have a source file that defines a symbol AAA which you do want to link and also references a symbol BBB which you don't want to link, the only way to resolve this is to change your source code to put the definition of the symbol in a different file, to create a different object file, than the code that references BBB.

If you can't change the source files, you could also create a dummy version of that symbol BBB in one of your object files so it's defined and then the "real" version of that symbol will not be loaded.  But this is definitely a hack and should only be used if you can't fix this the correct way.

Many thanks for you answer mate. Yeah it is exactly what I finally did, that is to create a dummy stub library that contains all undefined yet unused symbols, such that the missed are added while no further unresolved symbols will be introduced. However, I occasionally observed some phenomenon that certainly violates the rule, as shown in the latest edit of the question, kindly teach and correct if any misunderstanding.

@PkDrew This answer is inaccurate in several details. 1. Some UNIX linkers (most notably LLD) do not care about library order. 2. On ELF you can extract a single function out of an object file without source changes if you compile that object file with -ffunction-sections (also use -fdata-sections for a good measure).

I explained how linkers "broadly" work.  I didn't intend to give every possible nuance that can be obtained by using special options of specific linkers (the question didn't specify what toolchain was being used).  Whether the linker is a traditional single-pass linker or not, doesn't matter to the original question.
